# How to limit the IO for postgres for a particular python script?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, ubuntu

I have a server with nginx, gunicorn, django and postgres, which serves a website. In the background I need to have a script that is continuously consuming an external API and writing to the database. Currently I'm hitting the IO limit of my SSD (looking at `nmon` data) and as a result the website is very slow when the script is running.

I read something about `ionice` that it can set an IO priority for a PID, but putting that on the python script doesn't help, because it's the postgres process that's doing the work.

Is there a way to have a separate postgres process dedicated to that particular python script with limited IO?

Comment: Have you tried to use [Pgpool-II](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pgpool-II)

Comment: I haven't, but it seems like it's for a different purpose than what I need, if I understand correctly?

Comment: `continuously consuming an external API and writing to the database.` Try to reduce the volume of writes (eg by suppressing idempotent updates) Does it UPDATE/DELETE, too? Do you have FK constraints?

Comment: It only does create and delete on rows that absolutely need it, no unnecessary updating. There are no foreign keys on that table.